Получение расположения файла из ресурсов консольного приложения C#
Есть звуковые .wav файлы, добавленные в ресурсы консольного приложения(c#) через настройки. Чтобы их проиграть, надо получить их расположение. Чтобы не делать это вручную на компьютере, надо получить местоположения файлов из программы(для вставки в System.Media плеер). Пробовал искать ответ на вопрос в интернете, рабочего решения для звуковых файлов не нашёл.
Помогите, пожалуйста решить эту проблему!

А в чём проблема? Файлы ресурсов находятся там же, где и программа. Условный путь ./MyFile.wav (или даже просто MyFile.wav) сработает

По факту метка "файл ресурсов" (почти) просто значит скопировать данные файлы к билду

@Швеев Алексей Разве программа сможет найти файл по названию, если файл просто находится в ресурсах программы? (Надо сделать так чтобы работать с ними можно было автономно, на любом ПК) Пока не имею возможности проверить на практике, если это так, то спасибо.

А как ещё по вашему файлы находить?) Опять же, файл ресурсов это файл, который помещается вместе с файлами программы.

При добавления ресурса, вам генерирует код для обращения к этому ресурсу, обычно это Ресурсы.ИмяРесурса (Resources.SomeAudio). Сам аудио файл скорей всего вы добавили как массив байт, а значит и ресурс вам вернет byte[]. В свою очередь, System.Media (я так понимаю речь про SoundPlayer) просит от вас либо путь, либо поток (Stream). Вот у вас собственно 2 пути: 1. Скопировать полученные байты на диск и проиграть аудио от туда. 2. Загрузить все в память и уже из памяти воспроизводит. 2-й вариант будет таким: using var stream = new MemoryStream(...); .. new SoundPlayer(stream);.

@МихаилСвиридченко Что то вы сюда какие-то фреймворки приплетаете. Если мы говорим о действии сборки внедрённый ресурс, то это просто таргет, который копирует файлики в $out директорию (или типа того). Билд акшон Ресрус вроде как можно использовать только с wpf, иначе он ничего не делает. Для консольных приложений никаких подобных автоматизаций нет, да и они были бы излишне, так что не путайте человека.

@ШвеевАлексей "в ресурсы консольного приложения(c#) через настройки" - ПКМ по проекту - Свойства - Раздел "Ресурсы" - Создаете - Добавляете нужные данные - Собираете - Получаете .exe или .dll файл, внутри которого зашиты те данные, что вы добавили как "ресурс", это не файл рядом с исполняемым, это ресурс самого исполняемого.

@МихаилСвиридченко Ого, не знал. В любом случае скорее всего это перебор для него. Как по мне легче пометить файл как внедрённый ресурс и всегда копировать, после чего можно просто new SoundPlayer("test.wav") (конструктор поддерживает путь до файла)
